list of charts continuing below instead of on the next page - Power BI Report Builder
I have a list of charts that I want to display. I want this list to continue below on the same page instead of on the next page (the remaining space on the page is enough). The following image shows what I get.
enter image description here
While the next image shows what I want to achieve
enter image description here
I have tried modifying the various Tablix properties but to no avail. The data format is a 4x1 matrix with the graph in the last row and the graph data in the 'Column groups' section.
enter image description here

If you can provide the .pbix file, this will be easy to analyze. You can use sample data that case if data is sensative.
